# "How could I" and "how could I have" in rhetorical questions

Tags: modal-verbs, perfect-aspect, backshifting, conditional-perfect, can-could

I have a question about using *could* and *could have* in rhetorical
questions.

I was watching a [video](https://youtu.be/3-esvGwDHCY) where a very old man
who was talking to a priest about his childhood asked the priest, “How
could I tell my father what music meant to me?” as a rhetorical question.

In this context, it is clear that it was completely impossible for him to
have told his father what music meant to him.

Therefore “telling his father what music meant to him” did *NOT* happen, so
he was talking to the priest about an event that had not happened.

As far as I know, “could have” is used for an event in the past that did
not turn out to happen.  For example, when I say *I could run* in the past,
this means I possessed the ability to run, so this is about something that
in reality *DID* happen.

However, when I say *I could have run*, this means despite my ability to
run, I did not run.  So this is about something that did *NOT* happen in
reality, but which I am saying it could hypothetically have happened.

Accordingly, when I say *I could not run*, this is about something that did
*NOT* happen in reality.  And when I say *I could not have run*, this is
about something that did *NOT* happen in reality and means even
hypothetically it was impossible.

So when I ask “How I could run?”, I understand it is a question about how I
had the ability to run. But when I ask “How I could have run?”, I
understand it is a hypothetical question about how I would have had an
ability to run that I did not in reality possess.

The difference I see between two is that when I ask “How I could run?”, my
running in the past *DID* happen. But when I ask “How I could have run?”,
my running did *NOT* happen but it could have happened if only some
circumstances had been met.

So my question is why the old man asked “How could I tell him what music
meant to me?” instead of asking “How could I have told him what music meant
to me?”, since telling his father did *NOT* happen, and, as far as I can
understand, he was talking about a purely hypothetical situation.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome (back) to our site, and thank you for taking the time to expand a bit on the previous instance of your question. I have edited it to more closely follow our normal formatting conventions here regarding italics, to make it easier to read by adding blank lines between logical paragraphs, and to ever so gently reword a point here or there for the sake of clarity. If in so doing I have mistakenly put any words into your mouth that you feel do not fit the sense of what you are trying to say, then by all means do please edit it to fix it to your liking again.

Answer (score 1):

This understanding is not correct:

> So when I ask “How I could run?”, I understand it is a question about how I had the ability to run. But when I ask “How I could have run?”, I understand it is a hypothetical question about how I would have had an ability to run that I did not in reality possess.

(By the way, you meant to write "How could I […]", not *"How I could […]".)

"How could I run?" is a perfectly valid rhetorical question, meaning roughly "I couldn't run." It is, among other things, the past tense of "How can I run?", which (if used rhetorically) means roughly "I can't run."

It's perfectly fine to use the conditional mood in rhetorical questions like this — we can change "How can I run?" to "How could I run?" and "How could I run?" to "How could I have run?" with little change in meaning — but it's also perfectly fine to *not* use the conditional mood.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It appears I have a flaw in my understanding of English grammar. But the point I am having trouble grasping is that if my running did not happen, that is to say, if the action  did not happen in reality, then I am talking about a hypothetical situation, and in past events, "could" is not the hypothetical modal, but "could have" is. So how could I possibly use "could" for a past hypothetical event that did not happen in reality.What is making the modal "could" which can't be used for past hypothetical statements usable in a question that is about a past hypothetical event?

Comment: After having thought for a while -actually for two days, I have been thinking about this question, so I just can't thank you enough-, is it that normally "how could I tell him?" would mean that I DID tell him and I ask about the way by which I DID tell him, but when used in a rhetorical question, I ask this question meaning the opposite of this assumption. It could perhaps be called a type of irony. I am using this question in a way different from, or maybe contrary to, its normal usage in questions about past ability. Is my new assessment correct?

Comment: @Nostradamus: No, your assessment is still wrong. "I'm not doing it" doesn't imply "I can't do it", and "I didn't do it" doesn't imply "I couldn't do it". "How could I tell him?", if meant non-rhetorically, doesn't presuppose that I *did* tell him, merely that I *could* tell him.

Comment: then can we say because "could" does not entail either the commission or the omission of the action, it does not have to be hypothetical since it doesn't necessarily contain something contrary to reality. So when I did not do something, I can say either I could do it, meaning I did have the ability to do it but did or did not use it or I could have done it, meaning I definitely did not use the ability. Then as the last question, can we say "could" leaves the question of whether I did it unanswered but "could have" definitely shows I did NOT do it?

Comment: ruakh: Excuse my curiosity but is it fair to say in daily uses, most of the time, when "I could V" is used, it is supposed that "I did V" but it is only supposed out of custom and does not necessarily have to be meant by "I could do V"?

Comment: Re: "Then as the last question, can we say 'could' leaves the question of whether I did it unanswered but 'could have' definitely shows I did NOT do it?": Not necessarily; consider e.g. "I don't remember for sure how I met him, but I could have used one of my contacts in the industry." (It's hard to make generalizations, because *could* has so many different meanings.)

Comment: Re: "is it fair to say in daily uses, most of the time, when 'I could V' is used, it is supposed that 'I did V' but it is only supposed out of custom and does not necessarily have to be meant by 'I could do V'?": I doubt it. I would bet that "I could V" usually does *not* mean "I did V".

Comment: yes it is so difficult to generalise could, so I have to be more precise. Let me put it this way: can we say that when used in respect of past ability, "could" usually assumes that he DID it, but it could be otherwise,as when I ask "how could I know?", whereas in respect of past ability, "could have" assumes that he DID NOT do it, but it could be again otherwise as when I say "He could have done it but I do not know if he actually did" ?. After all, it seems it all depends on the context as derrida puts it but I hope there is no error in the above general rule, is there?

Comment: Re: "when used in respect of past ability, 'could' usually assumes that he DID it": I doubt that.

Comment: I see. At this rate, the new trouble I have to tackle is the difference between saying "He could do it but I don't know if he did it" and "he could have done it but I do not know if he did it". Is the difference related to the nuance between doing something and having done something? I mean, is the difference that in the former his doing it is present by the time in the past but in the latter it is complete by the time in the past?

Comment: It's the same as the difference between "He can do it tomorrow" and "He could do it tomorrow"; they're basically synonymous, but the former is a bit more "direct" and the latter is a bit more "remote". The choice between them *may* be affected by whether he actually did/will do it, but it's not a decisive factor.

Comment: thank you so much for helping. I wish I could give something in return as a gift other than my compliments .

Comment: I am so sorry for troubling you after all this time but I want to ask a question on this same topic. Do you think the following sentence is gramatically correct (could in this context means the past version of can, indicating past ability) : he could run away from his problems but he thought it would have been too cowardly so he had decided to confront them.

Comment: @Nostradamus: No, I don't think that's right; it should either be "he could run [...] it would **be** [...]" or "he could **have** run [...]".

Comment: I see. If I change "would have" to "would", I can still use "could" as the past version of can. What I am trying to say in this sentence is that he had the ability to run away, but as you said before, he did not use his ability because having the ability is something, and using it is something different. As for "would have", he did not run away, so he thought of a hypothetical situation in which he would have run away and decided it would have been cowardly. Why can I not use "would have" in this sentence? People keep saying I should use could have and I do not understand why.

Comment: @Nostradamus: That's a really good question. If we transpose your example to the present tense, we get "He can run away from his problems, but he thinks it would be too cowardly, so he's decided to confront them", which is not completely idiomatic IMHO ("could" would be better than "can", unless the sentence is in direct reply to a question like "Why can't he run away from his problems?"), but is nonetheless much better than your past-tense example, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Nostradamus: Actually, a further realization: even with "could have run", I still prefer "would be" rather than "would have been". ("He could have run away from his problems, but he thought it would be too cowardly, so he had decided to confront them.") So the big problem is probably the "he thought it would have been too cowardly", where the "would have been" sounds like it's referring to an earlier time than the "thought". So interesting!

Comment: I have been tackling this question for quite a while and no one could unfortunately give me a definitive answer. My main question is concerned with "could" in this context. I am not a native speaker but "could have" sounds better to me too, because it gives a sense of indirectness, of uncertainty, which harmonises with his not running away despite having the ability. But still all natives said could is wrong, rather than could sounds odd so could have should be used. I had always thought could does not imply did after your first answer to this thread but it seems it is much subtler than that.

Comment: : Beside the problem of using would have or would, If I change the sentence this way, does it sound correct? "he could run away from his problems but he thought it would be too cowardly so he had decided to confront them.". People still keep telling me I should use "could have" because I cannot be sure of my ability unless I use it, and when I say I've never counted to 300 but I can right not, I am sure of my ability, they they still say I should use "could" at present, and "could have" in the past. Why doesn't "I'd never counted to 300 but I could" work? I am literally lost in this

Comment: @Nostradamus: It's a good question. *Could* is sometimes just called the "remote" form of *can*, because there are so many different types of remoteness that it can denote: past tense, conditional mood, politeness . . . "can but won't" is perfectly valid, but the remote form feels more appropriate.

Comment: @Nostradamus: But the people saying "I cannot be sure of my ability unless I use it" are definitely wrong; for example, "I can [...]" is a common formula for offering to do something, and anyway *could* still generally involves confidence that one could do something if only the specified conditions were met.